# A Stupid Question About $O(3)$ Group

Tags: group-theory

I have a stupid question about $O(3)$ group.

Is it true that $SO(3,R)=O(3,R)/Z_{2}$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes (if you mean $Z_2=\{\pm I\}$). $O(3,\mathbb{R})$ consists of two components: $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ and $-I \cdot SO(3,\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Hi Spark Thanks. But I am still very confused. We know that $SU(2,R)/Z_{2}=SO(3)$. This seems imply that $SU(2,R)=O(3,R)$, which would be a disaster.

Comment: You mean $SU(2)/Z_2=SO(3)$? But that doesn't mean that $SU(2)=O(3)$ because we use different quotients. In terms of topology, $SU(2)$ is a connected covering of $SO(3)$ where $O(3)$ just consists of two identical copies of $SO(3)$, so it is disconnected.

Comment: Hi Spark. It is in standard QM text book, right? http://www.cmth.ph.ic.ac.uk/people/d.vvedensky/groups/Chapter9.pdf

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much for your help! I didn't realize that we are using different quotients.

Comment: I tell my students there's no such thing as a stupid question. Perhaps you're puzzled by something that _ought to be_ easy - but for you it isn't, so ask (as you did). That's not stupid.

Comment: Thank you so much for your encouragement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  As Spark mentions, the subgroup $N = \{\pm I\}$ is normal in $O(3,\mathbb{R})$, is isomorphic to $Z_2$, and
$$
O(3,\mathbb{R}) / N \,\cong\, SO(3,\mathbb{R}).
$$
Indeed, $O(3,\mathbb{R})$ is the internal direct product of $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ and $N$, so
$$
O(3,\mathbb{R}) \,\cong\, SO(3,\mathbb{R}) \times Z_2.
$$
In general, $SO(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a quotient of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $n$ is odd.  Specifically, the argument above only works for odd values of $n$ since $-I \in SO(n,\mathbb{R})$ when $n$ is even.  Moreover, a normal subgroup of order two in a group $G$ must be contained in the center, and the center of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ is $\{I,-I\}$, so if $\{I,-I\}$ doesn't work then nothing will.

Comment: Hi Jim. Thank you so much for your help. Your reply is truly inspiring with all the details that enlightened me.

Jim, thank you for shining like the star that you are. You brighten my life with your radiance. 

Wish you have a nice day.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Good point.  I have added the phrase "of order two".